# Why is origen-testers uppercasing all V93K flags?

Tags: origen-sdk

I noticed the origen_testers plugin is [uppercasing all of the V93K flow flags](http://origen-sdk.org/testers/api/OrigenTesters/SmartestBasedTester/Base/Flow.html#on_condition_flag-instance_method).  Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the past we have been bitten by the fact that Teradyne enable words (rough equivalent of V93K flow user variables) are case sensitive.
So we force them all to upcase so that we can't be bitten again.

I don't know if V93K flow variables are case sensitive or not, but by implementing a convention like this I don't need to know or worry about it.

Comment: Well I think this is a problem for us as the V93K is case sensitive and our OSAT uses case-specific flags that we have to match exactly.  What are our options here?

Comment: Well, you've just made the case for why Origen does the right thing here. I would accept a PR that allows you to turn off the upper casing from the interface at your own risk if you want, but the current behavior must remain the default.

Comment: i agree with the approach, if all companies had the choice to pick and choose every flow variable.  there are cases where names were chosen previously and to change them would be green dollars.  in the end, the PR you describe is on the way.  thx